# Using a lot of IF statements within a FOR loop

Tags: java

Is there a simpler way to complete a task like this where I don't have to use a lot of IF statements.

```
for (int i = 0; i < registration.length(); i++) {
        char numberFromReg = registration.charAt(i);
        String yearFromReg = "";
        if (numberFromReg == '1') {
            yearFromReg += "1";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '2') {
            yearFromReg += "2";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '3') {
            yearFromReg += "3";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '4') {
            yearFromReg += "4";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '5') {
            yearFromReg += "5";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '6') {
            yearFromReg += "6";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '7') {
            yearFromReg += "7";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '8') {
            yearFromReg += "8";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '9') {
            yearFromReg += "9";
        }   else if (numberFromReg == '0') {
            yearFromReg += "0";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a switch statement.

Comment: Can you please elaborate registration.charAt(i) , it may hold the key to optimization

Comment: what do you need to do if the character is not a digit? ignore it?

Comment: Use `Character.isDigit(c)` to test if a `char` (`c`) is any digit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you just want the `numbers` so you can use `replaceAll` as

```
yearFromReg  = registration.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

`\\D` : mean non-digit values so `replaceAll` will remove all non-digit values from the string.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the general case of more elegantly handling multiple `if` statements which all compare the same value, but to different constants, you'd normally use the `switch` statement. That would work in this case, but it would still be overkill IMO.

In this case, you're building up a string with all the digits from an input string. One option is to use a `StringBuilder`, and just append any digit, e.g.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < registration.length(); i++) {
    char numberFromReg = registration.charAt(i);
    if (numberFromReg >= '0' && numberFromReg <= '9') {
        builder.append(numberFromReg);
    }
}
String yearFromReg = builder.toString();
```

(Yes, you could continue to use repeated string concatenation - using `StringBuilder` is more efficient and clearer though.)

Or you could use a regular expression to simply replace all non-digits with the empty string, effectively extracting all digits:

```
String yearFromReg = registration.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Or if your code readership isn't as familiar with regular expressions, equivalently:

```
String yearFromReg = registration.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: won't `Character.isDigit()` help in this case?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov: Not if the OP only wants 0-9, rather than including Arabic-Indic digits etc.

Comment: @YCF_L: Whoops, yes. Although there's no particular need to capture multiple non-digits.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're clearing the string each time by making a new string within the loop.

Syntax should be

```
Make empty string 
loop {
  build string 
} 
use string
```

But yes, the simpler way is just append the character to the string. It's not clear why you need if statements at all

However, it looks like you actually want to remove all non-digits from a string, in which case, you can `replaceAll("[^0-9]+,"")` on the starting string

Answer (score 0):

Check the switch statement, docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Other people's answer are actually more accurate for this specific question. You don't need to check for all the conditions here

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements are a good replacement for all those if else statements especially since the conditional is the same in each else if. Makes it easier to read and easier to write!

Here is an example of a switch case:

```
switch(numberFromReg){
   case '1':   yearFromReg += "1";
               break;
   case '2':   yearFromReg += "2";
               break;
}
```

Just add more cases for each else if statement